# How to create nested fragments view in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to create a nested fragment view with two fragments in which fragment will contain ListView/RecyclerView, second listview data will be dependent on first listview item.

It will be similar to product filter screen of any e-commerce application.

Please take a look at code below:

TestActivity.java which holds parent fragment:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    FilterFragment filterFragment = new FilterFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.filter_fragment_container, filterFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

}

layout file for activity activity_test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_test"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.splice.TestActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Parent fragment class FilterFragment.java

```
public class FilterFragment extends Fragment{


public FilterFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filter, container, false);
    return v;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    insertNestedFragment();
}

// Embeds the child fragment dynamically
private void insertNestedFragment() {
    Fragment childFragment = new TestFragment1();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment1_container, childFragment).commit();
}
```

}

Parent fragment layout file fragment_filter.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context="com.splice.views.FilterFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/filter_purchase_title" />

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment1_container"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</FrameLayout>
```

Child Fragment class TestFragment1.java

```
public class TestFragment1 extends Fragment {


public TestFragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_fragment1, container, false);

}
```

}

**In result it is just showing content of Parent Fragment not content of child fragment.**

I want to implement somthing like 
[image]

Please correct me if I am going for wrong approch to implement this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I spotted some problems on the code you presented:

1. ft.replace(R.id.filter_fragment_container, filterFragment); in
   the activity_test layout is called fragment_container. I am not sure
   if this was a typo, but just to be sure
2. in the fragment_filter.xml, the LinearLayout has the orientation vertical and the TextView has  android:layout_height="match_parent" pushing
       the next element, fragment, out of the screen. That's why, probably,
       you don't see the fragment.

In order to have the split layout left and right, you can make it like:

```
<LinearLayout ...
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2"> 

<View1 
...
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<View2 
...
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```